# Why doesn't $HOME change if I use sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I expected the -H option to give me the target user's environment.

```
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -H -u tanum echo $HOME
/home/nbest
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -u tanum echo $HOME
/home/nbest
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -i -u tanum echo $HOME
/home/nbest
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -H -i -u tanum echo $HOME
/home/nbest
```

This would allow me to say:

```
sudo -u tanum ls ~
```

and get the target user's home directory listing.  Not the case.  Is this caused by the `env_reset` default in `sudoers`?

If so does -H have any effect?  What is the safest way to override this behavior?

If not what is the intended effect of -H?

Please set me straight.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$HOME` and `~` get expanded by **your** shell, they are not interpreted by `echo`.

In other words, `echo` does not see `$HOME` as an argument. It actually sees `/home/nbest`. Therefore the following commands are **exactly** identical (in your case):

```
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -H -u tanum echo $HOME
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -H -u tanum echo /home/nbest
```

Whatever you try (`-H`, `-i`, ...) you will never obtain the wanted behavior. Because `$HOME` is replaced by your shell and your shell runs as your user. `sudo` does not affect your shell in any way.

---

To work around this 'issue' (which actually is a feature), you can start a new subshell:

```
nbest@geo:~$ sudo -H -u tanum sh -c 'echo $HOME'
```

(Note that I'm using single quotes to avoid expansion.) This way, the new shell `sh` will run as user *tanum* and print his home directory.

---

An another alternative is to use `~username`, which gets expanded to the home of that user, without the need of using `sudo` or `su`. Try:

```
nbest@geo:~$ echo ~tanum
```

Comment: Of course.  How embarrassing!  `sudo do what I mean`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. e.g. `sudo -H -u buildbot bash -c "echo $HOME"` gives me `/home/ubuntu`, which is the default user on some Ubuntu images.

Comment: @Cerin use single quotes to prevent expansion: `sh -c 'echo $HOME'`

Comment: note to future self: the opposite of `-H` is `-E`; preserve the calling user's environment

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
sudo -H -u tanum bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```