# Trying to execute command as root does not set $HOME to /root

Tags: bash, sudo

Im attempting to run a command as root but it is not working and I think the reason why is because when running the command sudo is not setting $HOME to /root but keeping it as /home/MYUSER the command im running is:

```
$ sudo -H -u root bash -c "echo $HOME"
/home/MYUSER
```

Ive also tried the following which results in the same:

```
sudo su -c "echo $HOME" root
```

Note the actual issue im having is trying to run kubectl commands which MYUSER does not have access to do so the command im actually trying to execute is:

```
sudo -H -u root bash -c "kubectl get pods"
[sudo] password for MYUSER:
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I think the issue is the $HOME thing because /root has the .kube directory but /home/MYUSER does not.

Comment: try using $ROOT instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes permit the interactive shell to expand `$HOME` before passing the arguments to `sudo bash`. You can verify this by setting your shell into debug mode:

```
$ set -x
$ sudo bash -c "echo $HOME"
+ sudo bash -c 'echo /home/steeldriver'
/home/steeldriver
$ set +x
```

Try instead

```
sudo -H -u root bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

or just plain

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

since `-H` is the default in currently supported Ubuntu versions. See also:

- [Why doesn't $HOME change if I use sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338447/why-doesnt-home-change-if-i-use-sudo)
- [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10)

Comment: Wow such a simple fix. Thank you.

Comment: @TheQAGuy sorry it likely doesn't help with your `kubectl` command issue though

Comment: It does not but at least now I know that probably not the issue. I actually found a way to do it. Im doing `echo -e "PASSWORD\n" | sudo -S sleep 1 && sudo -i -u root bash -c "export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf && kubectl get pods"` which seems to work.